# Change the tree a commit points to

Tags: git

My git repository was recently screwed up by a Nextcloud sync. This left it with a commit that was missing a tree.

```
broken link from  commit ddf33d3d1b8278e1fd0d395209f2dbbd168f45c6 (refs/heads/master@{1632991805})
              to    tree b34b983985fdbe6b1173e2c1e442577bfbf393c1 (refs/heads/master@{1632991805}:)
```

I would like to overwrite the missing tree with the tree in the next commit, so I can fix the issue while keeping my history. Simply rebasing, to drop the commit fails with `fatal: unable to read tree b34b983985fdbe6b1173e2c1e442577bfbf393c1`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're using any kind of file or folder synchronization tool to mirror your repository across multiple computers then know that this is not safe. It is not recommended, and as you've already observed, will likely lead to registry corruption. You should instead use a central git server, like github, and push/pull against that on all your devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can't change anything about any existing Git object.  So you can't change the tree to which some commit points.

That said, you don't *have* to do *that*.  Consider instead using `git replace`, which works for arbitrary objects: use `git replace` to make your Git use the next (or previous) commit's tree *instead of* the missing tree.  Just use the `git replace object replacement` syntax:

```
git replace b34b983985fdbe6b1173e2c1e442577bfbf393c1 ...
```

(fill in the `...` with the desired tree).

This *should* allow your rebase to progress.

Note: it's probably a good idea to back up the bad repository now (you can use a simple recursive copy), and then clone it to a new one once you have it adjusted as desired and discard (or at least stop using) the intermediate copy with the replacement.

Edit: `git replace` is being too smart, so use `git replace --edit commit-with-bad-tree` to work around that.  You'll still want to clone the edited clone.  To make *everything* show up in the clone-of-the-clone and then remove the traces of cloning the clone, use:

```
git clone file://<path> new-clone
cd new-clone
git fetch origin '+refs/*:refs/*'
git remote remove origin
```

and a subsequent `git remote add origin ...` if appropriate.

Edit 2: `git clone` will almost certainly fail as it won't obey the replacements.  You'll need to run `git filter-branch` (with no filters), which intentionally damages the bad repository in the name of fixing it (not great although probably harmless in the end), or use [the new `git filter-repo` command](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to make the corrected clone.  I haven't tried the latter myself, so I don't have any particular instructions here.

Comment: I found the tree of the next commit, but the commands yields: error: Objects must be of the same type. 'b34b...' points to a replaced object of type '(null)'.

Comment: Ah. Git is being too smart for anyone's good here, it's reading the type out of the object and failing to read the object and deciding that it has a null type (!). You can try adding `-f` and see if that makes it happen, or resort to creating `refs/replace/b34b983985fdbe6b1173e2c1e442577bfbf393c1` manually with `git update-ref` (a replacement ref with R replaced with T is just refs/replace/R with value T, internally).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `git replace` on the *commit* object, with `git replace --edit <hash-of-commit>`.

Comment: Hmm. I tried -f but it didn't seem to do anything. Editing the commit itself created the replace ref, but didn't fix the issue to `fsck`'s statisfaction. However I read that it ignores replace refs, so... issue fixed?

Comment: `git fsck` deliberately disables replacements as it has to *check* everything. The goal here is to get rebase and other less-paranoid items to read the replacements as if they're good. The point of cloning the `git replace`-d clone is to get rid of the need for replacements, making a new clone that `git fsck` and other maintenance programs can handle correctly: this makes your edited repo "the real story" (even though it isn't, in some sense).

Comment: Now I am unable to clone the repo. It seems to fail with the same error I was having before `remote: fatal: bad tree object b34b983985fdbe6b1173e2c1e442577bfbf393c1`. However I can now rebase to before the commit. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, it may not be possible to clone the repository without first running a no-op filter-branch on it. Or perhaps it would be better to use the new `git filter-repo`, which has the side effect of copying the repository while obeying the replacements, to do both at once. I haven't tried this myself but it should work.

Comment: Using `git filter-repo --path-glob "*" --force` cleared up the issue! Thank you so much!